# Looping through Object containing two different arrays in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I'm currently working on a chat program written in VueJS and have a problem when trying to display the message with a given timestamp, because I need to loop inside an object containing two arrays (message array and timestamp array)

My data object looks like this:

```
messages: [     //saving text-messages of each chatroom in order (0 => chatroom1, 1 => chatroom2, ..)
        {      //chatroom1 with static data for testing
           text: ["first message chatroom1", "second message chatroom1"],
           time: ["08:38", "09:02"]
        },
        {      //chatroom2
           text: [],
           time: []
        },
        {      //chatroom3
           text: [],
           time: []
        }
]
```

When I would try to loop only through the text[] Array, my code would look like this:

```
<p class="message-class message-send" v-for="messages in messages[values.num].text">{{ messages }}</p>
```

giving me back

```
<p class="message-class message-send">first message chatroom1</p>   //messages[0].text[0]
<p class="message-class message-send">second message chatroom2</p>  //messages[0].text[1]
```

The [values.num] is the number of the selected chatroom passed in order to select the specific data (0 for chatroom1, ...)

When trying to iterate through text and time in one single loop (surely I want the time to be displayed beyond every single text message and not after all messages) I thought something similar to this should do the work:

```
<div v-for="messages in messages[values.num]">
       <p class="message-class message-send">{{ messages.text }}</p>
       <span class="message-time-send">{{ messages.time }}</span> 
</div>
```

The problem in this case is that I display the whole text and time array without iterating through the arrays itself.

Trying something like

```
<p class="message-class message-send">{{ messages.text[some number] }}</p>
```

also doesn't work.

Is there anyone who can help me solving this problem? Or should I consider trying to build the messages object in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
<div v-for="(message, index) in messages[values.num].text">
   <p class="message-class message-send">{{ message}}</p>
   <span class="message-time-send">{{ messages[values.num].time[index] }}</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works pretty fine. Didn't knew there that there is such a way to solve this problem

Comment: Hi again @FurkanSelcuk, your welcome. but because you are new contributor here I have to mentation. comments are used to ask questions or point out problems. please say thank by vote the answer or choose one of them as a correct one !

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a structure like this would be preferrable:

```
messages: [
  [ // room 1
    {
      "time": "08:38",
      "text": "first message chatroom1"
    },
    {
      "time": "09:02",
      "text": "second message chatroom1"
    }
  ],
  ...
]
```

Because logically, timestamp and message text are both properties of one single "chatroom message" item. But if you can't or do not want to change your structure, you can get the index in a `v-for` statement like this: `v-for="(message, index) in messages[values.num].text"` (see the [official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#example-1)). Then you can use that same index to access the corresponding item in the time array:

```
<div v-for="(message, index) in messages[values.num].text">
  <p class="message-class message-send">{{ message}}</p>
  <span class="message-time-send">{{ messages[values.num].time[index] }}</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I guess that I would also prefer a structure like the one you mentioned (I'm currently trying to get it done, but have some issues in pushing in new messages inside the messages object)

The code part itself works fine, like @Alireza already suggested